Razorpay integration error on python django
Unrecognized feature:
'otp-credentials'. error occured in browser console while razorpay integration and Method Not Allowed (POST): /checkout/ in terminal

[TerminalBrowser Console](https://i.sstatic.net/Kn6QfxTG.png)
HTML
script and button already loaded above
<script>
    var options = {
        "key": "rzp_test_THuJCWTGTSyCOm", // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
        "amount": "{{ razoramount }}", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
        "currency": "INR",
        "name": "Anasulfiros", //your business name
        "description": "Purchase Product",
        "order_id": "{{ order_id }}", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
        "handler": function(response){
            console.log("success")
                var form = document.getElementById("myform");
                // alert(form.elements["custid"].value);
                // alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
                // alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
                // alert(response.razorpay_signature);
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/paymentdone?order_id=${response.razorpay_order_id}&payment_id=${response.razorpay_payment_id}&cust_id=${form.elements["custid"].value}"
        
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#3399cc"
        }
    };
    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp1.on('payment.failed',function(response){
        alert(response.error.description);
    });
    document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
        console.log("button click");
        rzp1.open();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
{% endblock payment-gateway %}

views
class checkout(View):
    def get(self,request):
        user = request.user
        add = Customer.objects.filter(user=user)
        cart_items=Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
        famount = 0
        for p in cart_items:
            value = p.quantity * p.product.discounted_price
            famount = famount + value
        totalamount = famount + 40
        razoramount = int(totalamount * 100)
        client = razorpay.Client(auth=(settings.RAZOR_KEY_ID, settings.RAZOR_KEY_SECRET))
        data = {"amount":razoramount,"currency":"INR","receipt":"order_rcptid_12"}
        client.set_app_details({"title" : "Django", "version" : "1.8.17"})
        payment_response = client.order.create(data=data)
        print(payment_response)
        order_id = payment_response['id']
        order_status = payment_response['status']
        if order_status == 'created':
            payment = Payment(
                user=user,
                amount=totalamount,
                razorpay_order_id=order_id,
                razorpay_payment_status = order_status
            )
            payment.save()
        return render(request,'app/checkout.html',locals())

Please help me to find solution

Please don't use images for code or error text.
